# Proportional distribution based on open amount

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Following data represents incoming and outgoing transactions of two loans.
Transaction ID (t_id) represents order in which transaction events happen.

```
+---------+------+-----+--------+
| loan_id | t_id | amt | t_type |
+---------+------+-----+--------+
|       1 |    1 | 100 | OUT    |
|       1 |    2 |  20 | IN     |
|       1 |    3 |  30 | IN     |
|       1 |    4 | 150 | OUT    |
|       1 |    5 |  15 | IN     |
|       1 |    6 |  25 | IN     |
|       1 |    7 |  40 | OUT    |
|       1 |    8 | 200 | IN     |
|       2 |    1 | 150 | OUT    |
|       2 |    2 |  50 | OUT    |
|       2 |    3 | 120 | IN     |
|       2 |    4 |  20 | OUT    |
|       2 |    5 | 100 | IN     |
+---------+------+-----+--------+
```

Target is to proportionally distribute incoming amounts to outgoing amounts based on outgoing transaction open amount at the transaction event time of incoming amount. Each loan should be handled separately.
Following logic should apply:
loan_id: 1
1) Incoming transactions 2 & 3 should be 100% allocated to outgoing transaction 1 as it is only outgoing transaction at the time.
2) Incoming transaction 5 should be allocated 25%/75% between outgoing transactions 1 & 4. (transaction 1 open amount is 50, because 50 is repaid by transactions 2 & 3 and transaction 4 open amount is 150)
3) Incoming transaction 6 should be allocated 25%/75% between outgoing transactions 1 & 4. (transaction 1 open amount is 46.25 and transaction 4 open amount is 138.75)
4) Incoming transaction 8 should be allocated 20%/60%/20% between outgoing transactions 1; 4 & 7. (transaction 1; 4 & 7 open amounts are 40, 120 & 40 )
We can assume that total incoming amount and running total incoming amount is always less or equal to total open outgoing amount.

This is how final result should look like:

```
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+
| loan_id | in_t_id | out_t_id | allocated_amt |
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+
|       1 |       2 |        1 | 20            |
|       1 |       3 |        1 | 30            |
|       1 |       5 |        1 | 3.75          |
|       1 |       5 |        4 | 11.25         |
|       1 |       6 |        1 | 6.25          |
|       1 |       6 |        4 | 18.75         |
|       1 |       8 |        1 | 40            |
|       1 |       8 |        4 | 120           |
|       1 |       8 |        7 | 40            |
|       2 |       3 |        1 | 90            |
|       2 |       3 |        2 | 30            |
|       2 |       5 |        1 | 60            |
|       2 |       5 |        2 | 20            |
|       2 |       5 |        4 | 20            |
+---------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

Link to SQL fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/16623 
All combinations of 14 rows are generated, but not allocated_amt.

Currently I am not sure if it is possible to create SQL to generate such logic.
I tried to implement this using window functions, without any luck, because there is always need to know outgoing open amounts based on previous proportional distribution.
Maybe it is possible to create recursive query to cover this logic.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would be easier if you create a history table to store the distributions after each IN transaction so the next IN transaction can reuse the calculated values instead of trying to compute them on the fly. You will need an INSERT trigger for this - please take a look at the [SQLfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f814ba/32)

```
-- INSERT INTO distribution(loan_id,t_in,t_out,amount)
-- we compute the distributions for the current IN transaction and store them in table DISTRIBUTIONS 
-- to be used by the next IN transaction
SELECT current.loan_id,6 AS t_in,current.t_id AS t_out,25 * (current.amt - paid) / (total_due - total_paid) AS distributed
FROM 
-- first we get the amount paid for each existing OUT transaction
(SELECT t.loan_id,t.t_id,t.amt,SUM(d.amount) AS paid
FROM transactions AS t
LEFT JOIN distribution AS d ON t.loan_id = d.loan_id AND t.t_id = d.t_out
WHERE t_type = 'OUT' AND t.t_id < 6 -- only OUT transactions before the current IN transaction
GROUP BY t.loan_id,t.t_id,t.amt) AS current
LEFT JOIN
-- next we get the total amount due for the given loan
(SELECT loan_id,SUM(amt) AS total_due
FROM transactions
WHERE t_type = 'OUT' AND t_id < 6 -- only OUT transactions before the current IN transaction
GROUP BY loan_id) AS t_due                                                                   
ON current.loan_id = t_due.loan_id
LEFT JOIN
-- next we get the total amount paid for the given loan
(SELECT loan_id,COALESCE(SUM(amount),0) AS total_paid
FROM distribution AS d
WHERE t_out < 6 -- only OUT transactions before the current IN transaction
GROUP BY loan_id) AS t_paid
ON current.loan_id = t_paid.loan_id
WHERE current.loan_id = 1 -- the loan ID of the current IN transaction
```

Comment: Triggers in general are bad practice in database development. And there must be more efficient ways how to solve this.

Comment: It may be out of context but I've a friend who owns a company for access-control systems with RFID. He insists on using the raw events from the RFID readers (points in time) for the attendance reports - while I am using a trigger to combine points in time pairs into time intervals of presence in the building. In the end he is constantly struggling to build various complex reports (e.g. handling entrance before 24:00 and exit after 24:00, etc.) while I happily use a simple formula to see how much of each time interval overlaps with the work-time schedule. Wish you to find those efficient ways